# Unable to find a way to paginate through API data

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapy

I'm trying to use Python 3 `requests.get`to retrieve data from [this page](https://www.mwebexplorer.com/blocks) using its API. I'm interested in retrieving it using the data found [here](https://www.mwebexplorer.com/api/mwebblocks) and saving the entire table into my own JSON.

Here's my attempt so far

```
 source = requests.get("https://www.mwebexplorer.com/api/mwebblocks").json()
 with open('mweb.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(source, json_file)
```

I've looked through other questions in regards to pagination and all the other problems are able to write for loops to iterate through all the pages, but in my specific case, the link does not change when clicking **next** to go to the next page of data. I also can't use scrapy's xpath method to click next due to the entire table and its pagination not being accessible through HTML or XML.

Is there something I can add to my requests.get to include the entire JSON of all pages of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what browser you're using it might be different, but in chrome I can go to the network tab in devtools and view the full details of the request. This reveals that it's actually a POST request, not a GET request. If you look at the payload, you can see a bunch of key-value pairs, including a `start` and a `length`.

So, try something like

```
requests.post("https://www.mwebexplorer.com/api/mwebblocks", data={"start": "50", "length": "50"})
```

or similar. You might need to include the other parts of the form data, depending on the response you get.

Keep in mind that sites frequently don't like it when you try to scrape them like this.

Comment: thank you so much! That helps pull a lot more data:) One issue I'm having is that the two lines writing in the data into a json file do not work anymore:/ Is there a specific argument I need to pass when writing in POST data?

Comment: @boofa I forgot to put the `.json()` at the end of my line, I'd assume you still need it